# Couldn't match expected type ‘Map k0 a’

Tags: haskell

Below is my code:

```
module Data.Bag where

import Data.Map hiding (map)
import Prelude hiding (foldr)

-- | Type of bags
newtype Bag a = Bag {fm :: Map a Int} deriving Eq

-- | Empty bag
emptyBag :: Bag a
emptyBag = Bag empty

-- | Add an element to a bag.
bagInsert :: Ord a => Bag a -> a -> Bag a
bagInsert Bag{ fm=bag } a
  = Bag (insertWith (+) a 1 bag)

-- | Put all elements from a list into a bag.
listToBag :: Ord a => [a] -> Bag a
listToBag xs 
   = foldr (\x bag -> bagInsert bag x) emptyBag xs
```

I'm getting an error from the last function and the error statement is

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Map k0 a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a]
    (bound at /Users/.../Bags.hsproj/Bags.hs:20:11)
  listToBag :: [a] -> Bag a
    (bound at /Users/.../Bags.hsproj/Bags.hs:20:1)
In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘xs’
In the expression: foldr (\ x bag -> bagInsert bag x) emptyBag xs
```

I cannot seem to spot the source of the error. I referred to other posts made by users here that encountered similar issues but still, I am unable to understand the error `‘Map k0 a’`. So, how do I go around this?

Comment: `foldr` here refers to `Data.Map.foldr` and not `Prelude.foldr`.

Comment: When I first attempted this project, I received an ambiguous error and was suggested to use either `Prelude.foldr` or `Data.Map.foldr`. The `Prelude.foldr` eliminated the ambiguity but the other didn't. @Mephy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot seem to spot the source of the error.

`xs` is `[a]`, right? And *which* `foldr` are you trying to use? The `Data.List` one or `Data.Map` one?

---

My suggestion would be to update the compiler to 7.10 and use folds from `Foldable`.

Comment: Yes. I'm using `Data.Map` for  `foldr` @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: @skg22 and you're trying to use it on a list.

Comment: I tried using `foldr` from  `Data.List` but that didn't worked either :( @bartekbanachewicz

Comment: @skg22 Perhaps you could open a question with some details on what went wrong with `Data.List.foldr`. (When I try, it works fine.)

Comment: I tested your method where I have `import Data.List hiding (foldr)`. I received an ambiguous occurrence `'foldr’`. The program that I use, that is Haskell for Mac, indicates that it could refer to either `Prelude.foldr` or `Data.Map.foldr`. The `Prelude.foldr` eliminated the error but the other didn't @DanielWagner

Comment: @skg22 `import Data.Map hiding (map, foldr)`

Comment: That solved the problem. However, previously, I tried `import Data.Map hiding (foldr)` but that failed. Why didn't this work when it does the same purpose? Correct me if I'm wrong @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: @skg22 because there are more conflicting functions in those two modules than just `foldr`.

Comment: Understood. Appreciate your aid @BartekBanachewicz